# R: Nested for loop to fill NA values of different columns

Tags: r, for-loop, nested, arima

I have an unbalanced dataset that resembles the table below

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(32,55,84,95,108,125,122,103,95, 91, NA,
         NA, 65, 78, 84, 94, 100, 107, 111, 99, 97, 92, 78, NA), nrow = 12, ncol = 2))
colnames(data) <- c("cars", "bicycles")
rownames(data) <- c("2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", "2022-03-01", "2022-04-01","2022-05-01",
                       "2022-06-01","2022-07-01","2022-08-01","2022-09-01","2022-10-01",
                       "2022-11-01","2022-12-01")
data
```

The NAs are always at the bottom and my intention is to fill them with a simple ARIMA model.

I would like to create a generic code which automatically takes care of the missing values every time I input an updated dataset. I have come up with the following code using a nested for loop but even though I manage to fill my initial table with the forecasted values, the second for loop seems to add extra rows:

```
columns_NA <- as.matrix(names(which(colSums(is.na(data)) > 0)))
columns_NA <- as.matrix(match( columns_NA, colnames(data) ))

# First for loop runs for as many columns have NAs and need to be filled
for ( i in 1:as.numeric(nrow(columns_NA)) )  {
  
  NA_number <- as.numeric( sum(is.na(data[,columns_NA[i]])) )
  column_rows <- as.numeric(nrow(as.data.frame(data[,columns_NA[i]])))
  column_arima <- as.matrix(data[,columns_NA[i]])
  column_arima_series <- as.matrix(column_arima[1:as.numeric((column_rows-NA_number)),])
  column_series <- ts(column_arima_series, start = c(2007,1,1), frequency = 12)
  arima_name <- auto.arima(column_series, seasonal = TRUE, trace = FALSE)
  fcast_name <- forecast(arima_name, h = NA_number)
  fcast_name_matrix <- matrix(t(as.numeric(fcast_name[["mean"]])))
    
    for ( j in as.numeric((nrow(data) - NA_number))+1 : as.numeric(nrow(data))   ) {
      
      k <- nrow(data)-j+1
      pot_pos <- as.numeric(nrow(fcast_name_matrix)-k+1)
      data[j,as.numeric(columns_NA[i])] <- as.numeric(fcast_name_matrix[pot_pos])
    }
}
```

When I'm doing it manually (i.e. assigning values to i and j) the code seems to be running correctly. However, when I'm running this j bloats to 33, rather than 12 which is the initial table's row length.

Comment: In this line: `for ( j in as.numeric((nrow(data) - NA_number))+1 : as.numeric(nrow(data))   )`, operator "`:`" takes precedence over "`+`". Thus use parentheses: `for ( j in (as.numeric((nrow(data) - NA_number))+1): as.numeric(nrow(data))   ) {`

Comment: Nevertheless i think your code is somewhat bloated i think you can do the same task with a couple of lines: `data[,1:2] <- apply(data[,1:2], 2, function(x) 
  if(i <- match(T, is.na(x), nomatch = 1) - 1)
  c(x[1:i], forecast(auto.arima(x[1:i], seasonal=T, trace=F), h=length(x)-i)$mean) 
  else x)
`

Comment: Thank you so much for both your answers. Helped me a lot. I'm a novice R user so any tips are very welcome.